# Making a special styled css grid with borders

Tags: html, css, drupal, bootstrap-4

quick question, how would u go around making this kind of effect in CSS?

[image: Design from pc]

The idea is that the grid is build with a bootstrap grid. So when the screen size gets smaller they first will go to 2 columns and on mobile 1.
So when there are 2 columns u only have the middle line and the bottom line.

Is this possible in css?

```css
 .icon-grid{
     -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 8px 30px #222);
      filter: drop-shadow(1px 8px 10px #222);
   
    padding: 75px;
    border-right: black 2px solid;
    border-bottom: black 2px solid;
    

 }
```

```html
<div style="color: black" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>
        
   
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: what do you try code  ??

Comment: the lines between de icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use box-shadow , without bluring them and downsizing them:

basic example to tune to your needs. (increase offset then, dowsize them with a negative value on the fourth value of spread-radius)

```css
.icon-grid {
  box-shadow: 5px 0 0 -3px gray, 0 5px 0 -3px gray;
  padding: 75px;
}
:nth-child(4) .icon-grid {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 -3px gray;
}

/* demo purpose */
.row {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="color: black" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>
        
   
</div>
```

---

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

> /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
>
> box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

---

Codepen to play with https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LLyJZO (5 rows )
[image: codepen screenshot]

Comment: Thanks alot! will look into it to understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine but include bootstrep css and js in your code..

```
<div style="color: black" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p> <img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></p></div>


</div>
```

Comment: The bootstrap grid is working fine, i am talking about the lines between the icons. But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox and custom border definitions via pseudo classes.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
  <li><img alt="" class="icon-grid" src="https://cdn-accept-www.enfocus.com/sites/combell-accept-www.enfocus.com/files/media/product-pages/pitstop-pro/low-resolution.png"></li>
</ul>
```